# How do I automate data sanitization of linked models in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, sanitization

In order to have best up to date protection for users against XSS attacks the data should rather be sanitized when displayed to users rather than at the moment of db insert, if I got this at all correct. So my question is can I automate data sanitization in CakePHP so that the linked models automatically retrieved by Cakes queries are sanitized at point of queries as well? Or should I always manually loop calls for all the linked models' sanitization methods?

Comment: Are you looking for a kind of cron job? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All output that is not passed through one of the core helpers or foreign helpers that are known to take care of it should be passed through the [h() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h) in the views.

```
echo h($model['Model']['name']);
```

If you want to do it in the model the [Model::afterFind()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_afterFind) callback is the right place to modify the data. But I would not recommend to sanitize everything there because there are cases like editing the data or exposing the same data to an API or as JSON that might require no or a different sanitization.

See [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and [HtmlPurifier for CakePHP](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-html-purifier) as well. It is a strong filter and sanitation lib.

Comment: Thanks, afterFind () is exactly what I was looking for! I'm already using HtmlPurifier for embedded code and wysiwyg inputs. So far it has made more sense to me to regard sanitization as the models responsibility but I'll need to think about it further as I'll need to build an API soon enough. Thank you for bringing this up!

Comment: IMO the Model is not the best location for this; in this case, sanitization is targeted *for usage inside HTML*. Since the data coming from the Model may be used for other purposes as well (export to a CSV document?), each 'presentation' requires different Sanitization, therefore I would opt to do the escaping inside the view and create a simple helper to (automatically) escape/sanitize all values.

Answer (score 1):

In your views, just use

```
<?php echo h($data['Model']['field']); ?>
```

[h](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#h) is a wrapper for htmlspecialchars().